# Terraform - Don't wait for autoscaling group destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, terraform

When using the [Terraform lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle) to manage our autoscaling groups, we are using the `create_before_destroy` flag so that our new autoscaling group (ASG) is created before destroying the current ASG. The issue I'm trying to solve is that it seems to take up to 10 mins for Terraform to destroy the current ASG.

[image]

Is there a way to start the destroy command and not wait for it to complete?

Comment: What is the specific use case here?

Comment: @JakubKania we deploy using terraform through our CD setup, but want to shave down the deploy time. Once the current ASG is triggered to destroy, we don't actually want to wait to confirm it has been destroyed, as it's already out of the load balancer and we can come clean it up manually later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When destroying an autoscaling group terraform by default will wait for all instances in the pool to terminate. You can force an autoscaling group to delete even if it's in the process of scaling a resource. This is not the default behaviour, Terraform will normally drain all the instances before deleting the group. You can bypass this by specifying `force_delete` on the ASG but it could leave orphaned resources which is the reason for the default behaviour.